# How to catch failed S3 copyObject with 200 OK result in AWSJavaScriptSDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property) on the S3.copyObject method in AWSJavaScriptSDK indicates the following:

> A copy request might return an error when Amazon S3 receives the copy
>   request or while Amazon S3 is copying the files. If the error occurs
>   before the copy operation starts, you receive a standard Amazon S3
>   error. If the error occurs during the copy operation, the error
>   response is embedded in the 200 OK response. This means that a 200 OK
>   response can contain either a success or an error. Design your
>   application to parse the contents of the response and handle it
>   appropriately.

However, no example is given of what that failure might look like, and the types associated with copyObject in the `aws-sdk` Node library (i.e. CopyObjectResult and  S3.Types.CopyObjectOutput) suggest that there isn't a place for a failed copy to be reported in a success response.

Does anyone know how to interpret this documentation? What is an example of a copy operation failing while returning a 200 OK to copyObject, and how would the caller know?

Comment: This https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html#getting-started-nodejs-install-sdk. But it serves to create bucket,may be you can use promise for  copyObject.

Comment: After digging, I would expect it to throw (if using async/await, otherwise have the `err` field in the callback populated) and have statusCode 200 in the error object, along with "SlowDown" or "InternalError" in the message fields (type AWSError).

Comment: Jeremi's got it. I grabbed links to the relevant pieces of the source code to add as a detailed answer. If I could figure out how to promote Jeremi's comment to a full answer, I'd award the bounty to it for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SDK itself massages 200 status OK responses into errors for specific API calls, including copyObject.

As of [this commit](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/commit/347f2d9b11deea1fd09bff960245801d47edbd5c) , the operations `completeMultipartUpload`, `copyObject`, and `uploadPartCopy` are [flagged](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/dfb49100f7db707a2479726f911ca31443f5a861/lib/services/s3.js#L13-L15) as able to return a status code 200 that is actually an error, and there is a [handler](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/dfb49100f7db707a2479726f911ca31443f5a861/lib/services/s3.js#L652) to coerce those responses into error responses.

Comment: To those that stumble upon this from searching for the C# equivalent, the same thing applies. The [handler](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/Model/Internal/MarshallTransformations/S3UnmarshallerContext.cs) throws an `S3Exception` if the 200 OK response is actually an error.

Comment: The same is true for the Ruby SDK: [handler](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/version-3/gems/aws-sdk-s3/lib/aws-sdk-s3/plugins/http_200_errors.rb) here.